# How do I change CFLAGS to -g -O0 when compiling node.js from source?

Tags: node.js, waf

I tried:

```
CFLAGS="-g -O0" ./configure
```

But it's still using the default flags `-g -O3` when `make`.

Any way to work around?

Answer (score 1):

`./configure --debug`

That automatically builds with `-g -O0`

Or you can edit `wscript` in the root directory of the node source tree, search and edit the line with "O3" in it, and re-run configure.  That will build your source tree with the arguments you want, but *without* `-Wall -Wextra -DDEBUG`.  Just in case that's what you want.

p.s. I found this out by: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "O3"` and running a couple of simple experiments.

Comment: I'm interested how you find the `--debug` option by `find`?

Comment: I read the source code to wscript.  It tells you where O3 is set. O0 is set above that.  Once I knew that, a little python familiarity led me to the opt definitions for debug, and there it was.  But `./configure --help` will tell you all the options, and the wscript source is fairly readable.